# Akka Streams takeWhile processing next element even after condition fails

Tags: java, scala, akka, akka-stream

I have a very simple actor that just prints the number :-

```
public class PrintLineActor extends AbstractLoggingActor {

  @Override
  public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
        .match(Integer.class, i -> {
          System.out.println("Processing: " + i);
          sender().tell(i, self());
        }).build();
  }
}
```

Now, I have a stream to print the even numbers until I encounter an odd element:-

```
  @Test
  public void streamsTest() throws Exception {

    ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("testSystem");
    ActorRef printActor = system.actorOf(Props.create(PrintLineActor.class));

    Integer[] intArray = new Integer[]{2,4,6,8,9,10,12};
    CompletionStage<List<Integer>> result = Source.from(Arrays.asList(intArray))
        .ask(1, printActor, Integer.class, Timeout.apply(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
        .takeWhile(i -> i != 9)
        .runWith(Sink.seq(), ActorMaterializer.create(system));

    List<Integer> result1 = result.toCompletableFuture().get();
    System.out.println("Result :- ");
    result1.forEach(System.out::println);
  }
```

I **do NOT expect** any element after 9 being processed aka being sent to actor. However, I see the number "10" also being processed by actor (but not 12) as seen in below output

```
Processing: 2
Processing: 4
Processing: 6
Processing: 8
Processing: 9
Processing: 10 //WHY IS THIS BEING PROCESSED BY ACTOR??

Result :- 
2
4
6
8
```

Why is 10 being processed by actor? How to stop this?

EDIT:

I have tried debugging by recording timestamp of events, just to see if 10 is being processed before 9 actually completes, but no, 10 is taken after 9 is processed fully. here are the logs :-

```
Before Ask: 2 in 1596035906509
Processing inside Actor: 2 at 1596035906509
Inside TakeWhile 2 at  in 1596035906509

Before Ask: 4 in 1596035906609
Processing inside Actor: 4 at 1596035906610
Inside TakeWhile 4 at  in 1596035906610

Before Ask: 6 in 1596035906712
Processing inside Actor: 6 at 1596035906712
Inside TakeWhile 6 at  in 1596035906712

Before Ask: 8 in 1596035906814
Processing inside Actor: 8 at 1596035906814
Inside TakeWhile 8 at  in 1596035906815

Before Ask: 9 in 1596035906915
Processing inside Actor: 9 at 1596035906915
Inside TakeWhile 9 at  in 1596035906916

Before Ask: 10 in 1596035907017 //so 10 is taken much after the 9 is processed fully
Processing inside Actor: 10 at 1596035907017

Result :- 
2
4
6
8
```

Also, if i replace the .ask with a direct .map(print..), then 10 does not get printed. So why this happens when actor.ask is involved is very strange to me.

Answer (score 1):

Because you `ask` printActor asynchronously rather than print synchronously. In your exact run:

- message 9 arrives at PrintActor, prints "Processing: 9"
- message 10 arrives at PrintActor, prints "Processing: 10"
- Your Akka stream receives the response message for message 9 from PrintActor, complete the Akka stream, therefore in the result there is neither 9 nor 10.

To solve the exact problem, remove the async ask and print synchronously instead. But not sure if PrintActor is just an analogy, let me know.

Comment: No, that's not the sequence of events. This stream is sequential with no parallelism. I have edited the question with some debugging logs to indicate the sequence of events. The actor is asked to process 10 after 9 is successfully processed.

Comment: I am not saying, 9 is processed later than 10. I am saying after PrintActor processes 10, your Akka stream receives the ask response from message 9, and complete the flow before it receives the ask response from message 10. That's why.

Comment: No, the ask response from message 9 comes much before the 10 is sent to actor. You can see this in the debug logs

Comment: Please update the code regarding where you print the logs

Comment: Hey, i put a map(x -> {print("Before ask: "+ x); return x;) before the .ask
I also printed the timestamp in the takeWhile. Also looks like the mapAsync/ask pulls element from the upstream as soon as it emits an element. So, like u said, theres no implicit way to do this :(

Comment: I still believe akka stream process message 9 response before sending out message 10. The timestamp you print shows there is a 100ms difference between the 2 events, which is too small to eliminate the possibility, because log doesn't necessarily show the order of events. But yah, no a good way to fulfil your request.

Comment: You are right, I hit it multiple times and looks like 10 reached actor before 9 reaches sink.

Comment: Glad to hear, can you help accept my answer? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The akka streams are buffering the values thru the different streams. Please note that 10 was precessed, but it is not part of the result. If you wish, you can configure the buffer size:

```
.ask(1, printActor, Integer.class, Timeout.apply(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)).buffer(1, OverflowStrategy.backpressure)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. This didn't work - 10 still gets processed by actor. I tried putting in the .buffer(1,..) before ask, after ask and the actor somehow still gets 10

Comment: Also, I do NOT want 10 to be processed

Comment: Unfortunately you cannot control the way akka streams are stopping. That is the best you can do. In order to better understand that, you can print the result in the sink, with timestamp, and see which one happens before. Repeat that several times. I am sure that at least once the 10 will be processed before 9 was rejected.

Comment: I have also added a delay of 100ms in the takeWhile(). So the 10 is taken off from source after the 100ms delay after the takewhile()